# In GLSL why is it only storage buffers and not uniform buffers that can have an empty array declaration?

Tags: glsl

I have the following code:

```
struct GridInfo {};
struct TextureGridResult {};

layout (set = 1, binding = 1) readonly uniform GridTextureArray
{
    GridInfo texture_grid_info[256];
}grid_texture_array[2];

layout (set = 1, binding = 2) writeonly buffer TextureGridResultsArray
{
    TextureGridResult textureGridResultsArray[];
}grid_sample_results[2];
```

In the first one, at binding one, if I take out the '256' and leave [] without specifying a size I get a compilation error:

> array must be redeclared with a size before being indexed with a
> variable

However if I change the 'uniform' to 'buffer' it compiles. And the one below it compiles too. Does this mean that the size must be specified only for uniform buffers but not storage buffers?

Answer (score 1):

An unsized array in an SSBO means that all remaining storage defined by the buffer it is associated with will be given to that array. That is, its effective size is runtime-defined, based on the memory bound at the time the shader is executed.

UBOs don't have this functionality because they generally have much smaller size limits than SSBOs. The minimum required UBO size is 16KB, while the minimum required SSBO size is 128MB. There simply isn't much point to allowing it for data that's so small.

Comment: Is it OK to set it to a bigger size than what's bound to save you from writing difference shaders? So just leave it at 2048 but bind a buffer that's only 64 there and access accordingly?

Comment: @Zebrafish: Wouldn't it be easier to just bind a bigger buffer region? I haven't actually looked it up, but I wouldn't expect what you're suggesting to work.